# Getting undefined method on build_association for polymorphic has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, has-one

I'm a newbie and this issue is really frustrating but I have no doubt anyone with experience will see the problem pretty quick.

I am getting an undefined method `build_address' from my CompaniesController. I have a polymorphic has_one relationship to PostalAddress from Company. As part of a sign-up form I am trying to create new company and associated address objects in CompaniesController new method. I am using the correct syntax for build on a has_one.

**Models**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :postaladdress, as: :address, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :postaladdress
end

class PostalAddress < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :address, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Controller**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def new
     @company = Company.new
     @address = @company.build_address
  end
end
```

**Migrations**

```
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :subdomain

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePostalAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :postal_addresses do |t|
      t.string :addressline1
      t.string :addressline2
      t.string :addressline3
      t.string :town
      t.string :county
      t.string :postcode
      t.string :country

      t.references :address, polymorphic: true;

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Nested Resources in routes.rb**

```
resources :companies do 
  resources :postaladdresses :except => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have a `has_one` association setup between `Company` and `PostalAddress`, you would need to use

`@address = @company.build_postal_address`

**UPDATE**

Association in `Company` should look like:

```
has_one :postal_address, as: :address, dependent: :destroy
```

Use `postal_address` and not `postaladdress` as your model name is `PostalAddress` and not `Postaladdress`

**NOTE:**

Just for reference, if you had `has_many` association, then it would have been as:

`@address = @company.postal_address.build`

For additional details, read about **[Auto-generated methods for Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kirti. '@address = @company.postaladdress.build' results in: 'undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass.. '@address = @company.build_postaladdress' results in: _NameError uninitialized constant Company::Postaladdress_. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your Rails version?

Comment: Rails 4.1 / Ruby 2.1.1

Comment: The alternative if you want to keep the original naming is to reference the name of the class you want to create with an additional `class_name: 'PostalAddress'` option on the `has_one :postaladdress`.

Comment: @Shadwell I think you meant to say `has_one :postaladdress`

Comment: @KirtiThorat Yes, I did. Thank you! Got caught between the two solutions.